# Dynamically adding content to RelativeLayout

Tags: android, android-relativelayout

Since I'm still just learning Android (and it appears Amazon says it'll be 2 months till I get the Hello, Android book) I'm still playing around with doing simple things.  I have no problem getting an icon to display with the click of a button on my RelativeLayout using [ImageView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html).  The code for creating it is as follows:

```
private int mIconIdCounter = 1;
private ImageView addIcon(){
    ImageView item = new ImageView(this);
    item.setImageResource( R.drawable.tiles );
    item.setAdjustViewBounds(true);
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams( LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT );
    if( mIconIdCounter != 1 ){
        params.addRule(RelativeLayout.RIGHT_OF, 1 );
    }
    item.setLayoutParams( params );
    item.setId( mIconIdCounter );
    ++m_IconIdCounter;
    return item;
}
```

and the code to add the item is:

```
Button addButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.add_new);
addButton.setOnClickListener( new OnClickListener(){
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        addContentView( addIcon(), new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams( LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT ) );
    }
});
```

When I click my button what happens is all the newly created views are placed atop one another.  I'd like them to be placed to the right of the next element.  I did a quick search on SO for articles relating to RelativeLayout and found some that were similar ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2963414/help-with-android-linearlayout-or-relativelayout), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4231797/how-to-load-layout-dynamically-at-runtime-in-android), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3961022/problem-adding-textboxes-dynamiclly-in-a-relative-layout), and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3515759/dynamically-adding-a-view-to-activity-layout)) but while these addressed getting the content into the RelativeView they didn't seem to address the positioning aspect.

What am I doing wrong?

EDIT:

My main xml looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/add_new"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/add_new"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It looks like you might be adding the view to the root of the layout xml instead of the RelativeLayout.

You could try:

```
RelativeLayout layout = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.my_layout);
layout.addView(addIcon());
```

Comment: so if my main xml is nothing more than a RelativeLayout and a Button within it, how do I access it?  Just like (R.id.main)?  I'll update my question to show you.

Comment: you need to give your relativelayout an ID with android:id="+@id/my_layout".

Then you can instance your layout in your code. so that you can add views to it. 

hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

you are creating new relative layout inside function call. So every time new relative layout created and it added in the view when click button . Use common relative layout.

Comment: he is creating new layout params each time, not a new layout.  it's the addContentView that is the problem.