# user inputted information which will add item to list view as well as create a button in a different activity

Tags: android

Hi I am still learning android development. what i'm trying to achieve is having an "add item" in a settings activity, which will add said item to the list view containing all user added items, but will also create a button in a different activity.

So user goes to settings, clicks "menu items" (which then shows a list of all items that have been added) they then can click the floating action button to add new item, that item will add to the list as well as create a button on `MAinActivity.`

I have looked at this question but its missing the listview part and the different activities. [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11710200/android-programmatically-adding-buttons-to-a-layout).

any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Where you are storing added items?

Comment: The items will be added to a SQLite database after being added.

Comment: So, in `onResume()` of main activity, access the database and add the buttons.

Comment: So I can just pull the info for each item from the database to add new buttons on the MainActivity? that seems easier then I was imagining lol