# Replace spinner with dynamically added N number of buttons

Tags: android, android-arrayadapter, android-spinner, android-button

Trying to replace spinner with buttons dynamically populated from database.
Normally spinner use array adapter and built-in List Item Layouts "android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item"etc. How should it be modified if instead of spinner you want to populate buttons?

How in the startQuiz() method Spinner spinnerDifficulty.getSelectedItem(); can be replaced with button index?

**HERE HOW IT  WORKED WITH SPINNER**

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_starting_screen);
spinnerDifficulty = findViewById(R.id.spinner_quizlist);
loadDifficulties();
Button startTest = findViewById(R.id.start_test);
startTest.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        startQuiz();
    }
});
}
private void startQuiz() {
ListQuiz selectedLevel = (ListQuiz) spinnerDifficulty.getSelectedItem();
int LevelListID = selectedLevel.getId();
String quizListName = selectedLevel.getName();
Intent intent = new Intent(StartingScreenActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
intent.putExtra(EXTRA_DIFFICULTY_ID, LevelListID);
intent.putExtra(EXTRA_DIFFICULTY_NAME, quizListName);
startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE_QUIZ);
}
private void loadDifficulties(){
QuizDbHelper dbHelper = QuizDbHelper.getInstance(this);
List<ListQuiz> LevelList = dbHelper.getAllListQuiz();
ArrayAdapter<ListQuiz> adapterLevelList = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, LevelList);    adapterLevelList.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
spinnerDifficulty.setAdapter(adapterLevelList);
}
```

**Modifications done, so far...**

```
private ArrayAdapter <ListQuiz> adapter;
private  Button autobutton;
public int categorySize;
private List<ListQuiz> categoryName;
private LinearLayout QuizListLayout;
private  Button levelButton;

 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_starting_screen);
autobutton = findViewById(R.id.autobutton);
loadDifficulties();

    QuizListLayout = findViewById(R.id.layoutForButtons);
    for(int i=0; i<categorySize;i++){

        levelButton =new Button(this);
        levelButton.setText("" + categoryName.get(i));
        levelButton.setId(i);
        final int index = i;
        levelButton.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        levelButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startQuiz();
            }
        });
        QuizListLayout.addView(levelButton);
    }
}

//startQuiz still same
private void startQuiz() {
ListQuiz selectedLevel = (ListQuiz) spinnerDifficulty.getSelectedItem();
int LevelListID = selectedLevel.getId();
String quizListName = selectedLevel.getName();
Intent intent = new Intent(StartingScreenActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
intent.putExtra(EXTRA_DIFFICULTY_ID, LevelListID);
intent.putExtra(EXTRA_DIFFICULTY_NAME, quizListName);
startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE_QUIZ);
}

private void loadDifficulties(){
    QuizDbHelper dbHelper = QuizDbHelper.getInstance(this);
    List<ListQuiz> LevelList = dbHelper.getAllListQuiz();
    categorySize = dbHelper.getAllListQuiz().size(); 
    categoryName = dbHelper.getAllListQuiz();
```

buttonlayout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:id="@+id/layoutForButtons">
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: create buttons programatically and add them to parent view.  check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11710200/android-programmatically-adding-buttons-to-a-layout

Answer (score 1):

you can add buttons dynamically to your layout just add linearLayout in your XML file where you wants to add buttons.

```
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
 android:id="@+id/layoutForButtons">
</LinearLayout>
```

Create a varible of LinearLyout

```
LinearLayout layoutForButtons;
......
......
```

now initliase the varible  in oncreate

```
 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
 super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
 setContentView(R.layout.activity_starting_screen);

 layoutForButtons = findViewById(R.id.layoutForButtons);
  .....
addingButtonsDynamically(numberOfButtons);

 }

public void addingButtonsDynamically(int numberOfButtons){

 // for adding n number of buttons 
 for(int i=0; i<numberOfButtons;i++){

    Button buttton=new Button(this);
    button.setText("Button" + i);
    button.setId(i);
    button.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));


    // adding button to layout 
    layoutForButtons.addView(button);

 }

 }
```