# How to split SeekBar with transparent separators in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, split, transparent, seekbar

I'm using `SeekBar` to display a video timeline, and i want to show the `SeekBar` into `n` sections separated by transparent delimiter just like this:

[image]

I want to display one video as a story, so instead of having one `SeekBar` for the entire video, i want to split the `SeekBar` into these sections.

The four sections shown in the picture (above) are dynamic, i mean, for another video the number of divided sections could be 7 or 9 sections (mean the width of each section is calculated depending on the number of sections)

My question is: is the `splitting` the best way to do it (if yes, any hint?) or it can be done in different approach?

Thanks!

Comment: You can keep multiple seekbars by making their chain in constraint layout and make their visibility gone and make visible on basis of your requirements

Comment: Thank you @MuhammadFarhanArif actually it is a relevant solution, but i'm looking for something valid programmatically for all n sections..

Comment: ok well! you can make any View dynamically with java/kotlin without going through xml.

Comment: Do you have an example @MuhammadFarhanArif ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30284161/14333417