# How to run Android Apps in a computer browser like PWA App?

Tags: android, kotlin, progressive-web-apps

I would like to compare native with cross-platform technology.

I am writing `Kotlin Android Native` application and is it possible to easily open it in browser like `Chrome` and it will work similarly like web application in `Flutter`?
My goal is to write native application with possibility to launch it on 'normal' browser on computer.

Comment: I think there are some misunderstandings. The native android app should be developed in a way that is possible open it in a web browser. Mainly android apps are not developed to be opened in web a browser. For example: We can't open the free fire android game apk in a browser.  #1 How are you opening your android apk in a  mobile web browser? #2 Also your title question is silent different to the body question: How to write pwa on android and how run android in a web browser.

Comment: That's true it is my misunderstanding of the topic. It won't be a game just simple app with fragments do you think is it possible to somehow convert or open it in i.e. chrome on my laptop, computer?
My goal is to write native application with possibility to launch it on 'normal' browser on computer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Let's start with concepts

###### PWA

Progressive **Web** Application, as a summary is just a web with special javascript that make it possible the use of device(desktop/mobile) hardware features and/or css files with effects that make the **web look like a native application**. At the end is **just a web application** running a on remote server usually with a domain like [www.acme.com](http://www.acme.com) and accessed through a web browser.

UI Form elements are just html

###### Native mobile application

It is an application, developed with java or kotlin for android and Objective-C or Swift for ios. Result is an .apk or .ipa containing usually non readable files. This kind of application **cannot be opened using a web browser**.

UI Form elements are native components, not html

###### Mobile web browser

In a mobile device we have web browsers like opera, chrome, firefox, safari, etc. As we can notice, this are native applications capable of open any web page through its url. This is the feature provided by mobile devices used in the hybrid applications.

###### Hybrid Applications

A hybrid app is a software application that combines elements of both native apps and web applications where the core of the application is written using web technologies.

As a extremely summary, this apps are a kind of web browsers  opening just one url, without the address bar, which uses new device features to **trick the user** by displaying a website as if it were a native application

Usually the web application which is loaded in the hybrid applications are pwas or similar.

UI Form elements are just html.

Sources:

- https://ionic.io/resources/articles/what-is-hybrid-app-development
- https://www2.stardust-testing.com/en/blog-en/hybrid-apps
- https://easternpeak.com/definition/hybrid-apps/

### Your question

> How to run Android Apps in a computer browser like PWA App?

No, you can't. If you app is developed on a native language ([android sample](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11710264/3957754))

```
Button btnTag = new Button(this);
btnTag.setLayoutParams(new Layout...));
btnTag.setText("Button");
btnTag.setId(some_random_id);
```

**There is no way** to open it in a web browser of the same device and much less on another desktop browser.

### Workaround

If you application is a web with a valid url and you achieve to develop a kind of native app with features of browser (like [WebViews](https://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview) for android and [wkWebView](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/webkit/wkwebview) for ios), but hardcoding the url and hiding the address bar , you will have:

- a web able to opened directly any desktop browser
- a native app able to be opened on any mobile phone.

Keep in mind that the look & feel of your web should be similar to a native application like Material Design for [Angular](https://material.angular.io/components/toolbar/overview) or [React](https://mui.com/material-ui/react-app-bar/). Also should have advanced features like service worker in [pwa](http://progressivewebapproom.com/). Without them, your user will notice that is a web and not a mobile app.

[image: material design]

### Don't reinvent the wheel

The previous explained workaround is exactly what the following frameworks do but with steroids. The result app is called sometimes "hybrid applications". Basically you just develop html + javascript and the framework will package your code as a standard web, native .apk for android and native .ipa for ios. Here some frameworks:

- Apache Cordova
- React Native
- Flutter
- Ionic
- Phone Gap
- Unity (games)
- Apache Flex

[image: cross]

image source: https://www.statista.com/statistics/869224/worldwide-software-developer-working-hours/