# grid layout android studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I am trying to make an application that generates buttons with random color but I don't even know how to generate these buttons help!!

I have tried to do it with the manual that our teacher has offered us but it is incomplete

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener{


        public void onClick (View v){
        if (v.getClass().getSimpleName().equals("Button")) {
            Button b = (Button) v;

        }
    }


            public void Recorrer () {
                View v;
                GridLayout g = (GridLayout) findViewById(R.id.grLayout);
                for (int i = 0; i < g.getChildCount(); i++) {
                    v = g.getChildAt(i);
                    Button b;

                        if (v.getClass().getSimpleName().contains("Button")) {
                            b = (Button) v;
                            b.setOnClickListener(this);


                        }
                        Log.e("Objetito: ", v.getClass().getSimpleName() + "<--->" +
                                v.toString());
                    }

            }
            public void añadeHijos (){

                GridLayout g = (GridLayout) findViewById(R.id.grLayout);
                Button b;
                int iden;
                for (int i = 0; i < 18; i++) {
                    b = new Button(this);
                    b.setLayoutParams(new
                            ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
                    iden = View.generateViewId();
                    b.setId(iden);
                    b.setText("botón" + i);
                    g.addView(b, i);
                }
            }


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);



    }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

If randomly generate color or button try Math.random() and create array that contain colors and buttons text name. Try your luck here [Adding Buttons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11710200/android-programmatically-adding-buttons-to-a-layout)