# Got a blank page instead the layout xml file

Tags: android, xml

Hello :) I have a layout file with a red background and also a TextView but when I add this layout to my class, I just see a blank page.

Here is my MainActivity:

```
@SuppressLint("NewApi")
@SuppressWarnings("unused")
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements SensorEventListener {
    private SensorManager sensorManager;
    private Sensor accelerometer;
    private long lastUpdate;
    AnimatedView animatedView = null;
    ShapeDrawable mDrawable = new ShapeDrawable();
    public static int x;
    public static int y;
    public static final int width = 50;
    public static final int height = 50;
    public boolean firstDraw = true;
    private int screen_width;
    private int screen_height;
    private int sensorX;
    private Timer t;
    private int TimeCounter = 0;
    private TextView highscore_int;
    private int sensorY;
    private int time;
    private SharedPreferences prefs;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        highscore_int = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.highscore_int);
        SharedPreferences prefs = this.getSharedPreferences("myPrefsKey",
                Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        time = prefs.getInt("key", 0);
        highscore_int.setText("Highscore:" + time + "seconds.");
        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
        sensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);
        accelerometer = sensorManager
                .getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER);
        lastUpdate = System.currentTimeMillis();
        animatedView = new AnimatedView(this);
        setContentView(animatedView);
        t = new Timer();
        t.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
            public void run() {
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        TimeCounter++;
                    }
                });
            }
        }, 0, 1000);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        sensorManager.registerListener(this, accelerometer,
                SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_GAME);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        sensorManager.unregisterListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor arg0, int arg1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    @Override
    public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if (event.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER) {
            sensorY = (int) event.values[1];
            sensorX = (int) event.values[0];
            x -= sensorX * 3;
            y += sensorY * 3;
            if (x <= 0 || x >= screen_width || y <= 0 || y >= screen_height) {
                int oldScore = prefs.getInt("key", 0);
                prefs = this.getSharedPreferences("myPrefsKey",
                        Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                if (TimeCounter > oldScore) {
                    Editor edit = prefs.edit();
                    edit.putInt("key", TimeCounter);
                    edit.commit();
                }
                finish();
                Intent myIntent = new Intent(this, YouLost.class);
                startActivity(myIntent);
            }
        }
    }

    public class AnimatedView extends ImageView {

        Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
        Point size = new Point();
        static final int width = 50;
        static final int height = 50;

        @SuppressLint("NewApi")
        public AnimatedView(Context context) {
            super(context);
            // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
            display.getSize(size);
            screen_width = size.x;
            screen_height = size.y;
            mDrawable = new ShapeDrawable(new OvalShape());
            mDrawable.getPaint().setColor(0xffffAC23);
            mDrawable.setBounds(0, 0, screen_width, screen_height);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
            mDrawable.setBounds(x, y, x + width, y + height);
            if (firstDraw) {
                x = screen_width / 2;
                y = screen_height / 2;
                firstDraw = false;
            }
            mDrawable.draw(canvas);
            invalidate();
        }
    }
}
```

Here's my activity_main.xml:

```
   <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/actionbar_background"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/highscore_int"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="MyText"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textSize="40sp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

It doesn't really bothers me but I must have that textView to use an highscore for my app :)

Why I don't have the real xml file and only a blank page with a moving ball?

Comment: David, please, start formatting your code? Either use ctrl+shift+f in Eclipse or ctrl+shift+L in Android Studio...

Comment: there is no property for relative layout    android:orientation="vertical"          change that first

Comment: @WarrenFaith Did it -_-

Comment: @Rajajisubramanian You are right, but please look at Ved answer and see if you can figure out how to fix it

Comment: @DavidBalas if you did it, please update your question. The code here is really barely readable...

Answer (score 1):

> Why I don't have the real xml file and only a blank page with a moving
>   ball?

- Because you have set the content view two times. So the one defined later took the effect.

  ```
      @Override        
      protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
          super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
          setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
          setRequestedOrientation (ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
          sensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);
          accelerometer = sensorManager
                  .getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER);
          lastUpdate = System.currentTimeMillis();
          animatedView = new AnimatedView(this);
          //setContentView(animatedView);

          //more code
       }
  ```

Comment: You are right! but unfortunately, now my button is missing so my app is worthless :(

Comment: @DavidBalas - This is as expected. You should add view `animatedView` dynamically to the parent view.

Comment: Can you help me doing it ? :)

Comment: Take help from - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4269660/dynamically-adding-content-to-relativelayout. Rest leaving to you to try and figure out. :)

Comment: Emm.. I haven't figured it out.

Comment: @DavidBalas - Assign some id say `blabla` to your RelativeLayout in xml then get this view by id and then add the view `animatedView` after `animatedView = new AnimatedView(this);` by using `blablaLayout.addView(animatedView);`.

Comment: Never mind.. its not working to me.. app crashes because the line your_layout.addView(animatedView);

Answer (score 0):

Based on @VedPrakash answer and the comments there:

It is kind of simple. Call `findViewById()` to get your `RelativeLayout`, call on that layout the `addView(animatedView)` instead of the `setContentView()`. You will see the new added view then. As your `AnimatedView` is a custom view, you might want to check this resource about [custom views](http://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/index.html) and move the class into a stand alone file.

Comment: Never mind.. its not working to me.. app crashes because the line your_layout.addView(animatedView);

Comment: Crash means what? Do you have a stack trace you can share? Also update your code in the question to reflect latest changes

Answer (score 0):

add the following lines in your activity below this line

animatedView = new AnimatedView(this);

```
RelativeLayout layout = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.your_layout);
layout.addView(addIcon());

private ImageView addIcon(){
    ImageView item = new ImageView(this);
    item.setImageResource( R.drawable.tiles );
    item.setAdjustViewBounds(true);
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams( LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT );
 item.setLayoutParams( params );
    item.setId( mIconIdCounter );
return item;
}
```

check this solution and inform

Comment: inform me once you reach the goal

Comment: 3 Problems : 
1 ) `Tiles cannot be resolved or is not a field`
2 ) Which import? `I need to import LayoutParams but there are so many options` :P
3 ) `mIconIdCounter cannot be resolved to a variable`